# Unable to do code-first migration on .NET Core 1.0 (relation does not exist)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, asp.net-core

I had an existing RC1 project that I had worked on previously and recently upgraded to 1.0. Creating the migration works fine, but when I try to apply it to the database, I'm greeted with "Npgsql.PostgresException: 42P01: relation "Audasuite.Models.Answer" does not exist".

I found this [little blog](http://benjii.me/2016/05/dotnet-ef-migrations-for-asp-net-core/) and tried the part under "Keep Table Names from RC1", but it did not work.

This is my [project.json](http://pastebin.com/T6nPQ8Vu).

Comment: Did you had existing migration scripts (in the Migration folder) or new ones? Or did you created the initial migration from scratch? There has been a bug until RC2 which had issues on applying migrations when using generics models with non-standard types (i.e. guid). This resulted in some changes how constraints where named. I think it was a breaking change. I'd try to delete all migrations, then run an initial migration and see if it works

Comment: Yep that's what I ended up doing, was hoping there was a better way though.